# how can i call url from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

how can i call url or NSString from method in another class

Class 1

```
+ (NSURL *)createRequestURLWithChannel:(NSString *)channelName {
    NSString *sName = [channelName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"-"];
    NSString *channelvideo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sName];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
}
```

Class 2

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (PlayRowIndex == indexPath.row) {

            NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:channelvideo];
            AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
            AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
            playerViewController.player = player;
            [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


        } else if (StopRowIndex == indexPath.row) {
         //   Row stop
        } else if (RowIndex == indexPath.row) {
       //    Row 3
        }

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

i wanna call url `channelvideo` from method (`createRequestURLWithChannel`)  in class 1  and use it in method (`tableView`) in class 2

Comment: you need to import class 1's header in to class 2 and then create a instance of class 1

Comment: **NSNotificationCenter**

Comment: This is an instance method so you don't need to create any object. You can simply use this method by importing your class.
#import "Class1.h"
and use the method like this..
NSURL *url = [Class1 createRequestURLWithChannel@"ChannelName"];

Answer (score 0):

The way OOP (Object Oriented Programming) works with this is not so you can just call a function from another class like that.

For example let's say we have a class: "Orange".

Orange's source code tells the computer how to create an Orange and what the Orange should do.

Now we also have a class: "Banana".

In Banana we want to use an Orange's method (function).
To do this we must import the orange:

```
// in banana.h or banana.m
#import "Orange.h"
```

Now we must *create* an Orange:

```
Orange *myOrange = [[Orange alloc] init];
```

And finally call a method on it:

```
NSSmoothie *mySmoothie = [myOrange makeSmoothieWith: self];
```

Comment: also note that you must define Orange's method in Orange.h